# pop-over doesn't viewed properly

Tags: vue.js, popover

I'm trying to use popover in vue and it doesn't work for me.

can you please take a look on my code and tell me if I got something wrong?

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Popover from 'vue-js-popover'
```

```html
 <button v-popover:myPopover>popover</button>
   <popover name="myPopover">
  Hello
</popover>
```

Comment: Have you registered Popover with `Vue.use` ?

Comment: yes, as follow: Vue.use(Popover), and it's not working